# React - Multiple images upload timing is wrong (Firebase Firestore and Storage)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I am having some trouble trying to register data on both Firebase Firestore and Storage register at the right time.

I am using React and Firebase and I have a screen where the user registers a ball with its information as well as its images. Once the user has prompted that information, I use this Firebase function below. First, I register the newly created data, grab its ID and then use it to create a path in Storage and after that, I save the images uploaded by the user. Both data for Firestore and Storage are saving as they should, except for the timing.

The problem is that I get a response right after the ball information has been added and not until the images have finished been uploaded. Once I run the code below, I am getting a response immediately at where `console.log(resultCheck)` (Which is a promise) is and before `console.log(snapshot);`. I need to return both responses at the same time but I can't find the right asynchronous time.

```
  async registerBall(ball, images) {
    let result = await this.firebase.firestore()
      .collection("balls")
      .add(ball)
      .then(async function(ballResult) {

        if (images.length > 0) {
          var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
          let imageUploadResult = await images.map(async image => {

            let uploadTask = await storageRef
              .child("images/balls/" + ballResult.id + "/" + image.name)
              .put(image.file, { contentType: image.file.type })
              .then(snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot);
                return { isError: false };
              })
              .catch(error => {
                return { isError: true, errorMessage: error };
              });
            return uploadTask;

          });
          let resultCheck = { isError: false };
          imageUploadResult.forEach(result => {

            if (result.isError) {
              return (resultCheck = {
                isError: true,
                errorMessage: result.errorMessage
              });
            }

          });

          console.log(resultCheck);
          return resultCheck;

        } else {
          return { isError: false };
        }
      })

      .catch(function(error) {
        return { isError: true, errorMessage: error };
      });
    return result;
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is likely that you are trying to `await` your `images.map` when uploading which is actually returning an array of promises. To wait for all of them you can use `Promise.all`, i.e.:

```
const imageUploadPromises = images.map(async image => {...
```

Then:

```
const imageUploadResults = await Promise.all(imageUploadPromises);
```

Comment: I have managed to adapt all promises into the Promise.all. It has been a mistake to not check every promise. Thanks!